# Check elapsed time in PHP from a MySQL datetime

Tags: php, mysql

How can I check how many seconds past the current time to a time in my MySQL database?

Example: The current time right now is 2018-07-21 10:04:20, and the time in my database is 2018-07-20 21:58:40.

I want to get how many seconds past the datetime in my database to the current date time.

Comment: `strtotime` and math comes to mind... or on DB side https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: @user3783243, yes I can use strtotime but if I will subtract the strtotime(curr_time) - strtotime(db_time) = n = I don't know how to convert n to seconds

Comment: It will be in seconds because both values are the number of seconds since 1970.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **strtotime()** to convert your Date-Time to Unixtime an **time()** to get actual Timestamp:

```
    $timestamp = strtotime("2018-07-21 10:04:20"); //replace with your DB-date
    $diff =  time() - $timestamp ;                 //calculate the Difference
    echo $diff;                                    //negative number is in the future
```

Answer (score 0):

Just turn the date into number using `strtotime`.

```
$seconds = abs(strtotime($currentDate) - strtotime($dbDate));
```

I put `abs` in case of the result is negative.

`strtotime` returns the difference in seconds between `01-01-1970` and the date in parameter.

Comment: If it is negative it should probably go to `0`. You might be inverting the result greatly with the `abs`.

Comment: no, i mean there is a case where the date in db might be greater than current date

Comment: all datetime on my db is either equal to the current time or behind the current time. it cannot be ahead the current time